# std::thread move constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, move-semantics

I recently looked at this [std::thread](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread) reference.

For the move constructor it says:

> ```
> thread( thread&& other );
> ```
>
> Move constructor. Constructs the thread object to represent the thread of execution that was represented by
>   other. **After this call other no longer represents a thread of
>   execution.**

Also, in the example below there are these lines:

```
int n=0;
std::thread t3(f2, n);
std::thread t4(std::move(t3)); // t4 is now running f2(). t3 is no longer a thread
```

What I don't understand is what exactly happens with thread `t3` and `t4`?
Does `t4` waits until `t3` finish its execution? What does it mean that `t3` is no longer a thread?

Comment: "After this call other no longer represents a thread of execution".

Comment: That means what? That it stops its execution immediately?

Comment: There's a difference between a C++ object that potentially *represents* a thread of execution, and an *actual* thread of execution. It's similar to how `std::unique_ptr` represents potential ownership of some memory, but isn't itself memory. It's "resource handles" vs actual resources.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit this isn't actually helpful.

Comment: @A.Sarid: Actually, it is. Your misconception comes from not understanding what the word "represent" means. I linked to an in-depth description of the term. For free! You're welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::thread` isn't a thread. It is a representation of a thread provided by an underlying operating system that you can use to manipulate the thread. This is just like a `car` object isn't really a car.

`move` moves the thread being represented from one `std::thread` to another. After the `move`, `t3` is a gutless `std::thread`. The `std::thread` object is still there, but `t3` doesn't reference any actual system thread. `t4` now represents the thread previously represented by `t3`, but it will not wait unless you call `join`.

Comment: Ok! Makes sense now, your first sentence made it clear. Thank you!